# TrigExpand for numerical multiples of angles

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-value

After some calculations, Mathematica gives me a result which has in it a term `Cos[2.x]` (I cannot skip numerical computing, that's the reason for the `2.` there). However, I want to expand this expression and only have something with only `Cos[x], Sin[x]` in it.

I try `TrigExpand`, but this results in  `Cos[(2. + 0.i)x]` instead of the expected `Cos[x]^2 - Sin[x]^2`.

Does anyone have any idea on how to work around this problem? I tried to substitute `Cos[2θ]` for `Cos[2.θ]` but that doesn't seem to work (I suspect Mathematica somehow interprets this as a new symbol).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm skipping the part that tells you that you need to know what you are doing with your numerics. If you are sure your 2.0 is indeed a 2, you can use `Rationalize` to convert it

```
TrigExpand[Rationalize@Cos[2. x]]
(* Cos[x]^2 - Sin[x]^2 *)
```

This works in nested expressions as well

```
Sum[Cos[N[i] x], {i, 10}]
(* Cos[1. x] + Cos[2. x] + Cos[3. x] + Cos[4. x] + Cos[5. x] + 
 Cos[6. x] + Cos[7. x] + Cos[8. x] + Cos[9. x] + Cos[10. x] *)

TrigExpand[Rationalize[%]]
(* Cos[x] + Cos[x]^2 + Cos[x]^3 + Cos[x]^4 + Cos[x]^5 + 
 Cos[x]^6 + Cos[x]^7 + Cos[x]^8 + Cos[x]^9 + Cos[x]^10 - Sin[x]^2 - 
 3 Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 - 6 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^2 - 10 Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2 - 
 15 Cos[x]^4 Sin[x]^2 - 21 Cos[x]^5 Sin[x]^2 - 28 Cos[x]^6 Sin[x]^2 - 
 36 Cos[x]^7 Sin[x]^2 - 45 Cos[x]^8 Sin[x]^2 + Sin[x]^4 + 
 5 Cos[x] Sin[x]^4 + 15 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^4 + 35 Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^4 + 
 70 Cos[x]^4 Sin[x]^4 + 126 Cos[x]^5 Sin[x]^4 + 
 210 Cos[x]^6 Sin[x]^4 - Sin[x]^6 - 7 Cos[x] Sin[x]^6 - 
 28 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^6 - 84 Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^6 - 210 Cos[x]^4 Sin[x]^6 +
  Sin[x]^8 + 9 Cos[x] Sin[x]^8 + 45 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^8 - Sin[x]^10 *)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works! But I wonder, now that you mentioned nested expressions, what would happen if i wanted to apply `TrigExpand` in a trigonometric function which is, say, beneath a square root?

Comment: @AlexAiv. Have you considered using `ReplaceAll` (`/.`)?

Comment: @ChipHurst You mean in my original problem? I did try it but it didn't work. If you mean for the second question, using `TrigExpand` under square roots, I don't understand what you mean. What would I replace and with what?